# how to add constraints inside cellForItemAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift

I have a button inside this function

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellid", for: indexPath)

let editButton = UIButton()
editButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
editButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(click), for: .touchUpInside)
editButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 49/255, blue: 142/255, alpha: 1.0)
editButton.setTitle("Register", for: [])
cell.addSubview(editButton)
return cell
```

How can i add constraints like this?

```
editButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
```

Comment: and when i put that kind of constraints it has the error saying Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000275500 "UIButton:0x7fb1385337f0'Register'.left"> and <NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:0x600000275580 "UIView:0x7fb138508050.left"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
editButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
```

Also, it would be better to make a custom `UICollectionViewCell` and configure your button there or in storyboard, rather than adding this button in `collectionView(_: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt: IndexPath)`

Comment: jake i created a button inside a class of UiCollectionViewCell but the button is not clickable

Comment: let registerButton : UIButton = {
        let register = UIButton()
        register.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        register.setTitle("Register", for: [])
        register.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 49/255, blue: 142/255, alpha: 1.0)
        
        register.addTarget(self, action: #selector(registerUser), for: .touchUpInside)
        return register
    }()
    
    @objc func registerUser(){
       print("your here")
    }

Comment: it's not clickable, or you can't see it? creating a button with the code above make a clickable button for me

Comment: jake your code above show errors thats why i make it in the uicollectionviewcell so that i can make constraints but the problem is i cant click it